# issues during plotting arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I tried to create a fig and plot it, I did it and I needed to save my result in pdf format, but getting an issue

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
from sympy import *

a = np.loadtxt('hw1.txt')[0:100]


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure('HH')
plt.title("Aikyn's first figure")
plt.plot(a)
plt.xlabel('Urazalinov')
plt.ylabel('Aikyn')
plt.show()


plt.savefig('aikyn.pdf')
```

I got saved but the file is empty, could u tell me what is wrong
`<Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>`

Answer (score 1):

You should call `plt.savefig()` before calling `plt.show()`. When you close the image displayed by `plt.show()`, it is freed from memory.